# How can I use a standalone custom directive within a non-standalone component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular2-directives, angular-standalone-components

Using a standalone custom directive in a NOT standalone component

I created a custom structural directive and I want to be able to reuse it in different componentsa.
Everything works fine when it's not standalone, but when I add `standalone: true` it's giving me an error: 'imports' is only valid on a component that is standalone.
I don't want to make my component standalone as well, only the directive.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a **non-standalone** component, and when you want to use a **standalone** custom directives on it, you have to import the directives into the module file, i.e. `app.module.ts`.

Remember to only import, not declare your custom directives if they are standalone.

The `imports` property in a `@Component` decorator only applies for **standalone** component. If your component is not standalone and you try to add something to the `imports` property, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can import standalone directives into your modules in the same way you would import a module: https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#using-standalone-components-in-ngmodule-based-applications